# Using our old internet connection as a failback access

Tags: router, internet

We moved to another ISP recently, but we still keep our old plan too, which means we have one unused internet connection. We have netgear r8000 router on our old line, and an arris cable-modem/router on the new one. I know about dual wan routers, but I prefer not buying a new device.

My question is: is there any way (other that buying an extra dual wan router) to use our old internet connection as a fallback connection in case there is an outage in the main connection?

Comment: "any" way? If something happens, plug the old router back in. Otherwise, you're going to need *something* to do the checking and switching, and you don't want to buy a new device to do that, and you haven't said anything more about the network, software or hardware you have available...

Answer (score 2):

PfSense is capable of this, all you need to do is rummage around you're old hardware.  As a bonus, you can use various load balancing/QOS schemes like sending all you user Pandora/Netflix traffic over the old connection.

https://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/Multi-WAN

To add a little color: pfSense is a software router based on BSD Linux.  It can easily handle WAN speeds using an average or even old desktop.  The only thing you have to do hardware wise is add an extra NIC or two to an old desktop.

In sum: This isn't an 'Easy button' solution. It'll certainly take some fiddling/reading to get setup. It is though, a super powerful router/firewall that you try for essentially $0.  If you get it working, I suggest you'll never look back.

Comment: I guess this way you need an old pc with this software installed, and used as some kind of access point?

Comment: You actually don't even have to install the solfware, They have a live CD.  Just stick the CD in and boot!

Comment: That's great, the only problem is (in my understanding) that you need a pc with three ethernet port. Like for 1 and 2 for input for the two internet, and 3 as an output for a third router (which we have), which can be used as an access point, because the pc itself couldn't. So for this solution, we an extra ethernet card to the pc. Is this right?

Comment: "extra ethernet card to the pc." ... correct.  A little more difficult these days since you can't just grab them out of an old box (they're all build-in now), but you can get them off of Amazon for $10.  Remember you don't need Gig speed unless you've got a pretty special Internet connection :-)

Comment: PfSense is a nice option, but it will mean redesigning your network; at a guess right now you have one combined-modem-router doing NAT and DHCP, and to make use of this, you will need both modems set as bridges and have pfSense doing NAT and DHCP, or ... similar type of changes.